# How to convert `gulpjs` linve of codes into `clojurescript`?

Tags: gulp, clojurescript

I know using `clojurescript` to compile a `gulpjs` build tool would be overkill but how to convert these below into `clojurescript` just out of curiosity

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var markdown = require('gulp-markdown');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('intro.md')
        .pipe(markdown())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward interop, using the thread first macro it gets pretty clean

```
(def gulp (js/require "gulp"))

(def markdown (js/require "gulp-markdown"))

(.task gulp "default" (fn []
                        (-> (.src gulp "intro.md")
                            (.pipe (markdown))
                            (.pipe (.dest gulp 'dist'))))
```

Comment: tks so much for shedding light on my doubt :)